# Wordpress the excerpt VS the content

Tags: wordpress, blogs

http://hollywoodstunts.com/

under the slider there are 3 "intensive training" courses
they all display the excerpt

i need it to display the content, replacing the_excerpt() with the_content() didn't do anything

the plugin advanced excerpt didn't do anything

** aware when you click the blog posts, it goes to a jquery post, the client wanted it this way**

code:

```
   <div class="boxes">
    <div class="one box"><strong>September 9th - 27th
    November 4th - 22nd
    9am - 5pm
    Monday - Friday</strong>
    Tuition: $3,600.00
    Deposit: $600.00</div>
    <div class="two box"><strong>You Will Learn:</strong>
    Agility • Tumbling • Foot Falls • Bull Dogging • Armed Combat • Unarmed Combat • Martial Arts • Choreography • Trampoline • Mini Tramp • High Falls • Stair Falls • Window Penetration • Breakaways • Fire Gags • Car Hits • Near Misses • Air Ram • Air Ratchet • Harness Work • Special Effects • Marketing • Safety</div>
    </div>
```

or this
code:

```
<table>
<tr><td><strong>September 9th - 27th
November 4th - 22nd
9am - 5pm
Monday - Friday</strong>
Tuition: $3,600.00
Deposit: $600.00</td>
<td><strong>You Will Learn:</strong>
Agility • Tumbling • Foot Falls • Bull Dogging • Armed Combat • Unarmed Combat • Martial Arts • Choreography • Trampoline • Mini Tramp • High Falls • Stair Falls • Window Penetration • Breakaways • Fire Gags • Car Hits • Near Misses • Air Ram • Air Ratchet • Harness Work • Special Effects • Marketing • Safety</td></tr></table>
```

its supposed to look something like this on the homepage, with the image to the left:
[image: preview]

both don't seem to do anything

suggestions? help?

thank you in advance